# Calculate the angles of a triangle in Ada

Tags: ada

```ada
with Ada.Text_IO; use Ada.Text_IO;
with Ada.Integer_Text_IO; use Ada.Integer_Text_IO;
with Ada.Float_Text_IO; use Ada.Float_Text_IO;
with Ada.Numerics.Elementary_Functions; use Ada.Numerics.Elementary_Functions;
with Ada.Numerics; use Ada.Numerics;

procedure AdaO11 is
    procedure Calculate_Angles (Sa, Hc,    : in  Float; 
                                Va, Vb, Vc : out Float) is 
    begin 
        Va := Arcsin(Sa / Hc);
        Vb := Arccos(Sa / Hc);
        Vc := 90.0;
    end Calculate_Angles;
  
    procedure Angle_Program is 
        Hc, Sa : Integer;
        Va : Float;
    begin
        Put("Type in the length of the hypotenuse: ");
        Get(Hc);
        Put("Type in the opposite catheus: ");
        Get(Sa);
        New_Line;
        Put("Va: ");
        Put(Calculate_Angles(Va));
    end Angle_Program; 
      
    Selection : Integer; 
begin      
    Put_Line("Welcome to the calculator!")
end AdaO11;
```

So, I wonder why I am getting an error when I try to calculate the angles. Did I do something wrong? I really don’t see the error in this. I call in 2 parameters and then I send out 3. The error probably is in that part of my code.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What error(s) do you get? You try to call Calculate_Angels as a function, but it is a procedure.

Comment: Moreover, `Calculate_Angles` has five formal parameters, but you've only supplied one actual parameter.

Comment: There’s an extra comma in the parameters of Calculate_Angles. Fix that, and @trashgod’s comment applies. If you’re going to supply code, at least make sure it’s an [mcve]!!! Also, Wikipedia calls it a "cathetus".

Comment: @Jesper Quorning Yeah but I neee to do this with a procedure somehow but it won’t work

Comment: @trashgod I don’t really get what you mean as I I don’t see the error. The error I’m getting is that “Hc” in the parameter section is not called for

Comment: @Simon Wright, but it still won’t work…

Comment: @Simon Wright I minimized my code a bit so it might be easier to see

Comment: Mind that *won't work* is not a proper error description; you get an error message, so show us what it tells you. See also [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). In your case it is pretty obvious why the code doesn't compile as stated in the other comments. If you have difficulty to understand what the other users try to tell you with their comments, you might want to read a bit in the [Ada Wikibook](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Ada_Programming).

Comment: I explained the error in the comments. And I’ve read plenty of forums but I can’t find a solution. This is why I’m asking here.

Comment: What errors do your compiler emit? When I put the code into my compiler (GNAT FSF10) it emits two errors. `ada011.adb:17:39: identifier expected` and 
`ada011.adb:56:42: missing ";"`.

Comment: I can see the second error but that’s not my concern here. My concern is the identifier expected. For me it will say that Hc is not identified in my parameter. I don’t know why

Comment: When I fix the first two errors in the code above I get the error `adao11.adb:42:11: missing argument for parameter "Hc" in call to "Calculate_Angles" declared at line 17`. As @trashgod said: The procedure has five formal parameters. And as I said first: You have to call a procedure, not a function. See: https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Ada_Programming/Subprograms for how to call procedures and functions.

Comment: In `Angle_Program` you already get `Hc` and `Sa` from the user. You also have `Va` for one output from the procedure `Calculate_Angles`. You need to have variables for `Vb` and `Vc` also. Even if they are not needed.

Comment: @leun: In addition, the type of the actual parameters `Hc`, `Sa`,… should match the type of the formal parameters in `Calculate_Angles`— `Float`, rather than `Integer`.

Answer (score 3):

> I call in 2 parameters and then I send out 3.

Yes, your [subprogram](https://www.adaic.org/resources/add_content/standards/12rm/html/RM-6-1.html) named `Calculate_Angles` has five *formal* parameters, two with mode `in` and three with mode `out`.

> The error probably is in that part of my code.

No, the problem is where you [call the subprogram](https://www.adaic.org/resources/add_content/standards/12rm/html/RM-6-4.html) in `Angle_Program`:

1. `Calculate_Angles` is a `procedure`, not a `function`, so there's no result for `Put` to use.
2. You must supply actual variables in your call and they must match the formal parameters in number and type. As a result `Angle_Program` needs five variables—two from the user and three to hold the results of `Calculate_Angles`.

```
procedure Angle_Program is

   Hc, Sa     : Float;
   Va, Vb, Vc : Float;
begin
    …
    Calculate_Angles (Sa, Hc, Va, Vb, Vc);
    …
end;
```

As an aside, the trigonometric [`Elementary Functions`](https://www.adaic.org/resources/add_content/standards/12rm/html/RM-A-5-1.html) use *radians*. To match your `Vc` value, specify a suitable `Cycle` parameter to get degrees:

```
Va := Arcsin (Sa / Hc, 360.0);
Vb := Arccos (Sa / Hc, 360.0);
```

Typical output, which compares well with this [calculator](https://www.calculator.net/right-triangle-calculator.html?av=3&alphav=&alphaunit=d&bv=&betav=&betaunit=d&cv=5&hv=&areav=&perimeterv=&x=37&y=18), might look like this:

```
Type in the length of the hypotenuse: 5
Type in the opposite cathetus: 3

Va: 36.8699
Vb: 53.1301
Vc: 90.0000
```

> My concern is the identifier expected.

Given this,

```
procedure Calculate_Angles (Sa, Hc,    : in  Float;…
                                  ^
```

As @Jesper [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69399904/calculate-the-angles-of-a-triangle-in-ada/69410946#comment122681448_69399904), the corresponding error message is this:

```
 ada011.adb:17:39: identifier expected
```

This arises from an error in line 17 at position 39—a spurious comma. As you are declaring a subprogram's [*parameter specification*](https://www.adaic.org/resources/add_content/standards/12rm/html/RM-6-1.html), the compiler reasonably expects the [*defining identifier list*](https://www.adaic.org/resources/add_content/standards/12rm/html/RM-3-3-1.html#S0033) to have another *defining identifier* after the comma.